# OmniPay PayPal - Use certificate instead of signature API credentials

Tags: php, paypal, omnipay

I'm trying to use OmniPay PayPal for processing payment for a client.  The library uses the signature API credentials instead of the file-based certificate.  The client is unable/un-willing to change this on their end.  Is there a simple way to use the certificate within this library instead of the signature?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple way but I don't think it would be too complex to change the driver to support this.  Which of the PayPal Omnipay drivers are you using?  REST/Express/Pro?